# Struct: errors with initializers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For the code below, I get the following messages. These are:

```
1>c:\users\s1\desktop\c++folder\pr5\pr5\pr5.cpp(11): error C2078: too many initializers
1>c:\users\s1\desktop\c++folder\pr5\pr5\pr5.cpp(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
1>c:\users\s1\desktop\c++folder\pr5\pr5\pr5.cpp(13): error C2373: 'newBean' : redefinition; different type modifiers
1>c:\users\s1\desktop\c++folder\pr5\pr5\pr5.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'newBean'
1>c:\users\s1\desktop\c++folder\pr5\pr5\pr5.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

This is the code below. How can I please fix the code ? I have made the struct members to be static const.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 struct coffeeBean
{
    static const string name;
    static const string country;
    static const int strength;
};
 coffeeBean myBean = {"yes", "hello", 10 };
 coffeeBean newBean;
 const string newBean.name = "Flora";
 const string newBean.country = "Mexico";
 const int newBean.strength = 9; 

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

 cout << "Coffee bean " + newBean.name + " is from " + newBean.country << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are confused about something. `static` means that only **one**, global instance of that member exists for all objects. Therefore each `coffeeBean` cannot have its own name.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct coffeeBean
{
    string name;                     
    string country;                         
    int strength;
};
 coffeeBean myBean = {"yes", "hello", 10 };
 coffeeBean newBean;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

newBean.name = "Flora";
newBean.country = "Mexico";
newBean.strength = 9; 
 cout << "Coffee bean " + newBean.name + " is from " + newBean.country << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Couple of things:

If you want to initialize a variable, do not do it in global scope.

If you want to assign to variable, do not declare a type on it:

```
const string newBean.name = "Flora";//declare new variable, or assign to newBean.name ??
```

Just assign to it like this:

```
newBean.name = "Flora";
```

Use static, if you want to have a variable, that is common for all instances of classes. If you want a variable, that is different across instances (common use of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)), do not declare const.

And lastly, declare constants, if you do **not** plan on changing value.

Comment: I guess u could also place coffeeBean myBean = {"yes", "hello", 10 };
 coffeeBean newBean; inside main().

Comment: @solti It would be better, but it's legal and I would not want to change more, than is needed, to not confuse correctness with style.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct coffeeBean
{
    string name; // can't be static because you want more 
                 // than one coffeeBean to have different values
    string country; // can't be const either because newBean 
                    // will default-construct and then assign to the members
    int strength;
};
 coffeeBean myBean = {"yes", "hello", 10 };
 coffeeBean newBean;
 newBean.name = "Flora";
 newBean.country = "Mexico";
 newBean.strength = 9; 

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

 cout << "Coffee bean " + newBean.name + " is from " + newBean.country << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

fixed. see comments.